# Как реализовать Multi Touch для Unity Android

Tags: unity3d, android

Как реализовать Multi Touch для Unity Android. Есть кнопки и нужно просто чтобы они нажимались. Нет джойстиков и прочего, просто кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

Это мой скрипт (думаю всё понятно):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MobileInput : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void Update()
    {
        //Касания
        Touch[] touches = Input.touches;
        //Цикл
        for (int i = 0; i < touches.Length; i++)
        {
            Touch touch = touches[i];
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
                RaycastHit hit;
                Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.cyan);
                //Рейкаст
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
                {
                    if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Fruit" && !Values.gamePaused)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Полчай touch по индексу:

`var touch = Input.GetTouch(int index)`

У каждого тача бери позицию

`touch.position`

Проверяй state тача и область кнопок.

Answer (score 0):

Это вешаете на вашу кнопку в цикл Update, имена у кнопок должны отличаться

```
 // счетчик касаний
  int i = 0;
            // в цикле обрабатываем все нажатия на экран
            while (i < Input.touchCount)
            {
                // обрабатываем касание под номером i
                // если палец на месте, или двигается,
                // или палец только коснулся экрана
                if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved ||
                    Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    // от точки касания выпускаем "луч" и проверяем коснулся ли он нашей кнопки
                    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
                    RaycastHit hit;
                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
                    {
                        if (hit.transform.name == transform.name && hit.collider.name == collider.name)
                        {
                            // ваше действие
                        }
                    }
                }
                ++i;
            }
```