# Unity3d Реализация Мультитача

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть в GUI три 2D кнопки - влево, вправо, вверх. И мне необходимо реализовать одновременное нажатие кнопок. Ну, к примеру, одновременно нажимать 'вправо' и 'вверх'(Прыжок), что бы одновременно двигаться вправо и прыгать. Я прошу тех, кто знает скинуть сам код, так, как в теории я знаю как делать. Вот пример кода, который я нашел на форуме [Как реализовать Multi Touch для Unity Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/246696/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-multi-touch-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-unity-android) (Он прикрепляется в кнопки в цикле Update и у меня не сработал).

```
//C#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MobileInput : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void Update()
    {
        //Касания
        Touch[] touches = Input.touches;
        //Цикл
        for (int i = 0; i < touches.Length; i++)
        {
            Touch touch = touches[i];
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
                RaycastHit hit;
                Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.cyan);
                //Рейкаст
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
                {
                    if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Fruit" && !Values.gamePaused)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример взят с оф.документации ( https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/multi-touch-input )

```
public class TouchTest : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Update () 
    {
        Touch myTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        Touch[] myTouches = Input.touches;
        for(int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
        {
            //здесь делаешь все с твоими касаниями, которые хранятся в myTouches 
        }
    }
}
```

Постарайся искать в интернете перед тем как спрашивать... Это был первый результат по поиску "Multitouch Unity"

Comment: Это то я видел, но не понял, это нужно крепить к кнопке, или что то дорабатывать надо, тип проверка расположения тача и сравнение с координатами кнопки?

Comment: Создаешь скрипт TouchTest , вставляешь текст выше вместо класса. Дальше что именно тебе делать нужно я не в курсе, я не оракул. :) Если же у тебя есть на экране некая кнопка на которую ты должен кликнуть, то я не знаю она 3д на сцене или 2д. Если она 2д то я не знаю она реализована через GUI или NewGUI. Снова таки -- я не оракул. Если хочешь более точный ответ, то нужно давать более полную информацию. На твой вопрос выше я ответил более чем точно :)

Comment: Ок, у меня в GUI несколько 2d кнопок, для которых надо реализовать мультитач. При нажатии какой - либо кнопки, посредством мультитача, необходимо, что бы выполнялось какое - либо действие, ну к примеру ввывод текста.

Comment: он изначально должен поддерживать мультитач, на сколько я знаю. Просто когда рисуешь тогда же в GUI и задаешь что оно должно делать например в апдейте ```if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), btnTexture)) Debug.Log("Clicked button 1");``` . Просто создаешь нужное количество кнопок. PS: это устаревшая технология и если нужно много элементов интерфейса отрисовывать, то по возможности используй NewGUI.

Comment: ОК, спасибо, попробую.

Comment: отметь ответ правильным если проблема решена